# SQL Server trigger if update() with condition

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers

I have a table in SQL Server that has 3 columns: `ID`, `NAME`, `VALUE`.

This table has 2 rows with `ID=1` and `ID=2`.

(The value of ID doesn't change).

Every moment of time the value of column `VALUE` changes. Every time the column `VALUE` changes, I want to insert this updated value into a table (Device1 for ID=1, Device1 for ID=2).

I created a trigger for updating as if update(VALUE) begin...but it doesn't do the work.

Is there a way to add a condition in if update(VALUE) to work in each row

I used this query

```
Create Trigger insertIntoDevices
On ITEMS
For Update
As
    If Update(VALUE)
    Begin
        Insert Into table device1 
        Where ID = 1

        Insert Into table device2
        Where ID = 2
    End
```

With this query each update in column VALUE inserts VALUE into device1 and device1 and that duplicates values in my tables device1 and device2.

Comment: MySQL is not the same as SQL Server.   Please tag appropriately.

Answer (score 2):

Table creation on the below ;

```
 CREATE TABLE TestTable(
        ID      INT IDENTITY(1,1),
        Name    VARCHAR(5),
        VALUE   NVARCHAR(50)
    )
    
    GO
    CREATE TABLE device1(
        VALUE NVARCHAR(50)
    )
    GO
    CREATE TABLE device2(
        VALUE NVARCHAR(50)
    )
    GO
```

Insertion for ID=1 and ID=2

```
GO
INSERT INTO TestTable(Name,Value)
VALUES('Test1','test1'),('TEST2','test2')
```

Firstly,To find new values for each row you can use 'inserted' but it can be include non-changed data. For example: ID =1,Name='test1' and VALUE='test1' and updation of name column will be also included in inserted.

Secondly,To find old values for each row you can use 'deleted'.

After that we find the values that only includes updation for VALUE.

To Sump Up,
Finding Inserted rows and deleted rows will give us the result of each rows new  and old values. We used intersection (INNER JOIN ) to find only changed values.

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[insertIntoDevices]
   ON [dbo].[TestTable]
   AFTER UPDATE
AS 
BEGIN
    DECLARE @InsertedTable table (
        InsertedID      INT,
        InsertedName    VARCHAR(5),
        InsertedVALUE   NVARCHAR(50)
    )
    DECLARE @DeletedTable table (
        DeletedID       INT,
        DeletedName     VARCHAR(5),
        DeletedVALUE    NVARCHAR(50)
    )


    INSERT INTO @InsertedTable(InsertedID,InsertedName,InsertedVALUE)
    SELECT ID,[Name],[Value] FROM inserted;  

    INSERT INTO @DeletedTable(DeletedID,DeletedName,DeletedVALUE)
    SELECT ID,Name,Value FROM deleted;
    
    INSERT INTO device1(VALUE)
    SELECT  UpdatedValue    = it.InsertedVALUE
    FROM @InsertedTable as it
    INNER JOIN @DeletedTable as dt ON it.InsertedID = dt.DeletedID AND ISNULL(dt.DeletedVALUE,'') <> ISNULL(it.InsertedVALUE,'')
    WHERE it.InsertedID = 1
    
    INSERT INTO device2(VALUE)
    SELECT  UpdatedValue    = it.InsertedVALUE
    FROM @InsertedTable as it
    INNER JOIN @DeletedTable as dt ON it.InsertedID = dt.DeletedID AND ISNULL(dt.DeletedVALUE,'') <> ISNULL(it.InsertedVALUE,'')
    WHERE it.InsertedID = 2
END
```

To test I used the updation queries on the below;

```
 --Example 1
UPDATE TestTable
SET Value='selam'
WHERE ID = 1


--Example 2
UPDATE TestTable
SET Value='hi'
WHERE ID = 2
```